# The last request was denied because it contained an invalid security token

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

When uploading a large file, I'm getting this error message in Joomla:

> The last request was denied because it contained an invalid security token. Please refresh the page and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This error message occurs if you use a PHP version higher than the original script. Solution could be to update the component responsible for uploading the file (if an update is available) or downgrading the PHP version used - But if you use Joomla 3.8 you cannot downgrade as you will need the 7 version.